# Oracle ORDS takes 2 secs (slow) to respond to simplest query

Tags: oracle, tomcat, oracle-ords

Firefox and Chrome report ~2000ms response time (localhost) to my REST API.  The database executes the query in under 1ms.  A static JSON file with the same content is served in 4ms.

Where is all the time going?  Is ORDS.war consuming it, is it database connection time, is Tomcat using it or something else?  How do I find the root cause?

Update: Win10.  Stopped Apache service and tried running catalina.bat from command line and response time drops to ~30ms.  Killed it and tried running as a service again - response time consistently ~170ms.

I have an ORDS 3.0.11.180.12.34 service running on Tomcat 8.5.16 (jre1.8.0_144 x64) running this query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM dual
```

as below

```
DECLARE
l_handler_id        ords_metadata.ords_handlers.id%TYPE := NULL;
l_param_id          ords_metadata.ords_parameters.id%TYPE := NULL;

l_module_name       ords_metadata.ords_modules.name%type := 'rest';
l_pattern           ords_metadata.ords_templates.uri_template%type := 'select_1_from_dual';
l_method            ords_metadata.ords_handlers.method%type := 'GET';

BEGIN

ords.define_template (
    p_module_name => l_module_name,
    p_etag_type   => 'QUERY',
    p_etag_query  => q'~SELECT dbms_random.value(0,1) FROM dual~',
    p_pattern     => l_pattern
);

ords.define_handler (
    p_module_name => l_module_name,
    p_pattern     => l_pattern,
    p_method      => l_method,
    p_source_type => ords.source_type_collection_item,
    p_source      => 'SELECT 1 FROM dual'
);

COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: run ORDS in debug mode, capture the logs. you should get all the timings there. sounds like it's an issue with your connection pool - we have customer pulling tens of thousands of records in that same amount of time

Comment: add this to your defaults.xml file <entry key="debug.debugger">true</entry>

you could also try running ORDS in standalone mode to see if for some reason something funny in tomcat was happening, although most of our customers use tomcat with absolutely no issues

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Checked and I already had the debugger flag on because I was using it to debug error pages.  Looked through all files in  CATALINA_HOME/logs but was unable to see detailed timing information.  I have localhost_access_log with %D but that shows only total time.  Could you be specific about where I should be looking?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith "tens of thousands of records in that same amount of time".  A claim worth checking.  Tried SELECT * FROM table with 100K rows and 7 columns.  With a catalina.bat run command line startup Firefox DEV edition reports: 100K items, 16.91MB, Waiting: 44ms, Receiving: 1543ms.  Confirmed.  Don't know why I was getting a 2 sec penalty when starting as a Windows service.   Now can't reproduce.

Comment: I love happy endings...but I'm guessing it was taking time to establish a connection in your pool. I'm thinking it should def be in the catalina file, but I'll check for sure.